# How to take list of entity from another database table in java spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 classes in code and 3 tables in database. My classes have connection with third table. And one of them is list of variables. How can i connect to it with using spring boot annotation.

**ActiveIngredient.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "active_ingredient")
public class ActiveIngredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String ingredient;
    private Double gram; //Cannot connect to table
}
```

**Medicine.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "medicine")
public class Medicine {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "BarcodeNo")
    private String barcodeNo;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String medicineName;
    private List<ActiveIngredient> ingredients; //Cannot connect to table
}
```

This is my third table.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a many to many relationship between ingredients and medicine with gram as additional variable. Refer this : https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many#many-to-many-using-a-composite-key

Comment: Should i create one more class to implement third table?

Comment: Just 1 class should work and some changes in your original entities

Comment: I couldnt find way to do it.

Comment: https://thorben-janssen.com/many-relationships-additional-properties/ lmk if this is not enough, will try to create sample code.

Comment: I figure out to create new class to take variables. But i dont actually know how to do it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@SecondaryTable` it might work. [See this post in Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables#single-entity)

Behind the scenes, JPA joins the primary table with the secondary table and populates the fields. This solution is similar to the @OneToOne relationship, but this way, we can have all of the properties in the same class.

It's important to note that if we have a column that is in a secondary table, we have to specify it with the table argument of the @Column annotation. If a column is in the primary table, we can omit the table argument as JPA looks for columns in the primary table by default.

Also, note that we can have multiple secondary tables if we embed them in @SecondaryTables. Alternatively, from Java 8, we can mark the entity with multiple @SecondaryTable annotations since it's a repeatable annotation.

Comment: SecondaryTable is not used for n:m relations. It's used to have two tables for one entity.